# Where does "i" get its value in this LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm little perplexed by the behavior of this select LINQ statement. Just below the `LOOK HERE` comments you can see a select LINQ statement. That select statement is on the `employees` collection. So, it should accept only `x` as the input param. Out of curiosity I passed `i` to the delegate and it works. When it iterates through the select, it assigns 0 first and then it increments by 1. The result can be seen at the end of this post.

Where does the variable `i` get its value from? First of all, why does it allow me to use a variable `i` which is nowhere in the scope. It is not in the global scope neither in the local Main method. Any help is appreciated to understand this mystery.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeedId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>()
                                {
                                    new Employee() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" }, 
                                    new Employee() { FirstName = "Jacob", LastName = "Doe" }
                                };

            // LOOK HERE...
            var newEmployees = employees.Select((x, i) => new { id = i, name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName });

            newEmployees.ToList().ForEach(x => { Console.Write(x.id); Console.Write(" "); Console.WriteLine(x.name); });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

[image]

```
0 John Doe
1 Jacob Doe
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) has an overload that projects the current index of the element in the sequence. Also [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Enumerable.SkipWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549288(v=vs.100).aspx)/[`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb548775(v=vs.100).aspx) have it.  You can use it like a loop variable in a `for`-loop which is sometimes handy.

One example which uses the index to create an anonymous type to group a long list into groups of 4:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList();

List<List<int>> groupsOf4 = list
    .Select((num, index) => new { num, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 4).Select(g => g.Select(x => x.num).ToList())
    .ToList();  // 250 groups of 4
```

or one with `Where` which only selects even indices:

```
var evenIndices = list.Where((num, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

It might also be important to mention that you can use these overloads that project the index  only in method-syntax. LINQ query-syntax does not support it.

Comment: Worth noting: it's probably a good idea to name that lambda parameter "index", since it's not at all clear from the code what is happening (it's sort of hidden functionality).  Even the documentation is a bit obtuse.